# Solution to a differential equation involving inseparable variables.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

What is the solution for the following DE

$\frac{dy}{dx} - \epsilon{y} = x$

Where $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and  initial condition y = 1 when x = 0 and where $\epsilon$ is any positive parameter

Comment: Can you show any attempts that you have made? By showing your attempt, others will be able to point out any error you may have made and guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} - \epsilon y = x$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}  = x + \epsilon y$$

Let $v = x + \epsilon y$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}  = v$$
Differentiating $v = x + \epsilon y$
$$\frac{dv}{dx} = 1 +\epsilon\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dv}{dx} - 1}{\epsilon}$$
Substituting $\frac{dy}{dx}$ we have $$  \frac{\frac{dv}{dx} - 1}{\epsilon} = v$$
$$  \frac{dv}{dx} = \epsilon v + 1$$

Dividing by $\epsilon v + 1$ and multiplying by $dx$

$$\frac{1}{\epsilon v + 1} {dv} = dx$$
Integrating both sides
$$\int\frac{1}{\epsilon v + 1} {dv} = \int dx$$
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon}ln(\epsilon v + 1) = x + C $$
$$ln(\epsilon v + 1) = \epsilon (x + C) $$
$$ln(\epsilon v + 1) = \epsilon x + \epsilon C $$

$\epsilon C$ is just another constant (C)

$$ln(\epsilon v + 1) = \epsilon x + C $$

Raising both sides to the power $e$

$$e^{ln(\epsilon v + 1)} = e^{\epsilon x + C}$$
$$e^{ln(\epsilon v + 1)} = e^{\epsilon x}  e^C$$
$e^C$ is just another constant $C$.
$$e^{ln(\epsilon v + 1)} = Ce^{\epsilon x} $$
$$\epsilon v + 1 = Ce^{\epsilon x} $$
Substiuting $v = x + \epsilon y$
$$\epsilon(x + \epsilon y) + 1 = Ce^{\epsilon x}$$
$$\epsilon x + \epsilon^2 y + 1 = Ce^{\epsilon x} $$
$$\epsilon x + \epsilon^2 y = Ce^{\epsilon x} - 1$$
$$\epsilon^2 y = Ce^{\epsilon x} - {\epsilon x}  - 1$$
Generic solution
$$y = C\frac{e^{\epsilon x}}{\epsilon^2 } - \frac{x}{\epsilon} - \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} $$

Using the initial condition $y= 1$ when $x = 0$ we calculate for $C$

$$C\frac{e^0}{\epsilon^2 } - \frac{0}{\epsilon} - \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} = 1$$
$$\frac{C - 1}{\epsilon^2 }  = 1$$
$$C= 1 + {\epsilon^2 }$$

By substituting C the exact solution is
   $$y = (1 + \frac{1}{\epsilon^2 })e^{\epsilon x} - \frac{x}{\epsilon} - \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$$